# Get GCP service account JSON via Terraform script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

How can I download the service account JSON file of a service account created in the same script and save it in a defined directory on the VM (which, by the way, is also created by the Terraform script). I need to save it in JSON format, i.e. not just a specific attribute from the JSON key file.

The goal is to bypass the manual steps via GUI (ADD KEY > CREATE NEW KEY > JSON + transfer downloaded file to VM).

Is this possible and if so, can someone here help me how?
I have not found an analogous entry - only one with reference to Terraform Cloud, but it did not help me in this regard.

I tried it by using a metadata_startup_script, but I cannot get it done. I managed, for example, to write only the private_key to the file, but unfortunately not the entire JSON.

```
  # Use the service account to authenticate the GC cli
  metadata_startup_script = <<-SCRIPT
    # Create the directory for the service account key file
    mkdir -p ~/home/user/.gc && touch /home/user/.gc/sa_key_file.json
    
    # Write the service account key file
    echo '${data.google_service_account_key.dez-sa-key.private_key}' > /home/user/.gc/sa_key_file.json
    # echo "${jsonencode(google_service_account_key.dez-sa-key)}" > /home/user/.gc/sa_key_file.json
    # echo "${google_service_account_key.dez-sa-key}" > /home/user/.gc/sa_key_file.json
    
    # make files visible
    ls -a

    # Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable
    export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/user/.gc/sa_key_file.json
    
    # Authenticate the GC cli
    gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
  SCRIPT
```

Comment: `data.google_service_account_key.dez-sa-key.private_key`? The data source **can't** get you the private key, it would be insecure if that were to be possible. Only point you can get the private key is when creating it (i.e. via the resource). Moving ahead is there any reason you aren't simply using the [service_account block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#service_account) of the instance resource and trying to spin up a script for it instead?

Comment: If you use a startup script in your VM, you use a Compute Engine. And if you use a compute engine you no longer need a service account key file. If you don't need a service account key file, you have no issue! And you are safer!! But you could have issue to achieve what you want. Let us know for what you use the service account, we will help you to do the same without!